# import / export a theme prestashop 1.6

Tags: import, module, themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I tried to install the module "Import/export a theme", but after a simple search on Modules ---> modules, I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly but theme import/export is already part of prestashop.

```
Preferences -> Themes -> Buttons on top right -> Add new Theme/ Export theme
```